# Auth0 as front end to log in Cognito users

Tags: amazon-cognito, auth0

I have an Android app and an API secured with Auth0.

I'm developing an app for a new client, who has a large Cognito user pool.

Is it possible to use my current Auth0 setup to log in Cognito users via email/password and receive a Auth0 JWT?

I don't want to create a new Auth0 user for each Cognito user. At least not explicitly.

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for handling a similar situation. Could you find a way to login cognito users behind the auth0 without redirecting to cognito?

Comment: I didn't. Tried the Auth0 examples but couldn't get it working. :(

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use Auth0 as a service provider and AWS Cognito as an identity provider. In theory, you can use SAML protocol to achieve that. Try the following:

- Configure Auth0 as SAML service provider. https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-sp-generic
- Configure AWS Cognito AS Identity provider: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-console.html

Then, once you initiate the login flow in auth0, users will be redirected to AWS Cognito for user authentication. After successful user authentication, AWS should redirect the user Auth0 with SAML Assertion. In that stage, Auth0 will validate the assertion and will issue a JWT token. The user will be redirected to your application with JWT. Note that if this is the first login, auth0 will create a user profile. 
https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml

The following AWS documentation explains how to configure auth0 as IDP. 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auth0-saml-cognito-user-pool/

Comment: I want to keep my current Android login, which is using the Auth0's Java client library. With the SAML solution will users be bounced to my login screen to another login screen then back? I was hoping Auth0 could be set up to communicate with Cognito behind the scenes. I want to authenticate with the existing Cognito users using the Auth0 libraries, which I'm already using everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: In the case of SAML, the user will be redirected to Cognito. So, yes, there will be a different login screen. Currently, I can not think of a better solution. Both SAML & OIDC protocol performs the redirect which is also considered secure.